# How to pass Struct of array objects to a stored procedure and retrive struct values in stored procedure and perform db insertion

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have requirement to call stored procedure by passing sql STRUCT object.

The format STRUCT object contains (string,string,ARRAY)

I need to insert the first two string values in one table and ARRAY object values in another table along with id reference value from first table..

Please help me how to write stored procedure for it and mainly how to get array object values and insertion into second table.

Answer (score 0):

Create two tables as array type ,

```
CREATE TYPE array_table AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (50); -- Array of String

CREATE TYPE array_int AS TABLE OF NUMBER;          -- Array of integers
```

And a store procedure,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SchemaName.proc1 (p_array     IN     array_table,
                                              len            OUT NUMBER,
                                              p_arr_int      OUT array_int)
AS
   v_count   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   p_arr_int := NEW array_int ();
   p_arr_int.EXTEND (10);
   len := p_array.COUNT;
   v_count := 0;

   FOR i IN 1 .. p_array.COUNT
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (p_array (i));
      p_arr_int (i) := v_count;
      v_count := v_count + 1;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

And in your java class, where you are establishing `jdbc`

```
            String array[] = {"one", "two", "three","four"};                  
            ArrayDescriptor des = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("SchemaName.ARRAY_TABLE", con);
            ARRAY array_to_pass = new ARRAY(des,con,array);

            CallableStatement st = con.prepareCall("call SchemaName.proc1(?,?,?)");

            // Passing an array to the procedure - 
            st.setArray(1, array_to_pass);

            st.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
            st.registerOutParameter(3,OracleTypes.ARRAY,"SchemaName.ARRAY_INT");
            st.execute();
            System.out.println("size : "+st.getInt(2));     
            // Retrieving array from the resultset of the procedure after execution -
            ARRAY arr = ((OracleCallableStatement)st).getARRAY(3);
             BigDecimal[] recievedArray = (BigDecimal[])(arr.getArray());

            for(int i=0;i<recievedArray.length;i++)
                System.out.println("element" + i + ":" + recievedArray[i] + "\n");
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Hi San, Thanks for your effort,I could able to perform using array of structs passing to stored procedure. My requirement is  to pass STRUCT object to stored procedure and the struct object contains array object as one of object which I need to retrieve the array object from struct  and insert into a table and remaining struct objects in another table.